# PHP & SQL load URL and insert in IMG class

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am working on a web application. And I am having a problem right now in making it.

In the top bar it should load someone their photo in an img class.

Now this is what I have in SQL:

http://prntscr.com/cu5jop

And this is what I want in the img class

```
<img src="'$foto'" alt="user-img" class="img-circle">
```

the database connection file is included (php). How can I make this work?

**Database.php**

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sc******_1", "***************", "*******");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Kon geen verbinding maken met de database".mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Thanks all for your time and help!

`-` Justin

Comment: You should start with basic php/mysql tutorial such as how to select and display data from mysql using php.

Comment: @S.I. i was looking for an straight answer actually. Or do you have a link to that tutorial? :D

Comment: You said that you have included your DB connection. Did you also have query to database like `select images from table....` ?

Comment: @S.I. I think where you are talking about it exactly what I need, I included my database.php in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your connection included this is how you select and display image from your database. Just a starting point:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<img src="'.$row['foto'].'" alt="user-img" class="img-circle">';
}
```

But from what you've wrote in your question I think you also need login script and when user login you select from database image of that user.

It will be something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE user_id = ? <- id of the logged user.
```

You can start from here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: I already have an login system, yes. And it does work with an ID that is correct.

Comment: But if I put that script in the middle of my code (with the <?php and ?> tags ofcourse) it should work. But how can I make it select the right id? I mean when the session is started on that page it should automatically take their ID or not? Sorry I am quite new to PHP and I am trying to learn it. So far I am proud enough I could create an good login system with an SHA1 hashed passwords en user friendly error system when signing up and signing in. :P

Comment: Well once user is logged in you already have his id in the session

Comment: So if I put that code in the database.php it will grab the right info from the right id automatically? Sorry I am such a noob at PHP / SQL I am trying to get into it your link to w3schools.com was very helpful aswell! :D

Comment: This is another question. You should start new question and include there your login page and what exactly you want to do after user login.

Comment: I included my login/logout/page structure in the question and edited the title of the question a little bit. Is my login / logout configured good aswell or does it need to change to make this image load thing work? :)

Comment: I meant to start new question. It is not how SO work. It's not good to just change the title and question body to whole new question once you get answer. And to answer to your question - no, it is not good because you're vulnerable to sql injection. Also for what I see you store password in plain text which is HUGE security issue.

Comment: Something to get you start with: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: Sorry @S.I. I am kinda new to StackOverflow so thanks for the advice tho.. I can get started with this thanks

Comment: You're welcome  @JustinvanDongen. You can accept answer if it's helped you.